# $x' Ay=0$ is equivalent to $y' Ax=0$, $\forall\ x,y$, implies that $A'=A$ or $A'=-A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

$x' Ay=0$ is equivalent to $y' Ax=0$, $\forall\ x,y$, implies that $A'=A$ or $A'=-A$?

If $x'Ax=0$, $\forall\ x$, then $A'=-A$.

If not, then how to derive that $A'=A$.

Here $A'$ is the transpose of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Prove first that if $\phi$, $\psi$ linear functionals $\colon V \to k$ such that $\phi(x) = 0 \implies \psi(x) = 0$, implies $\psi = c \cdot \phi$ for some constant $c\in k$.

Now consider $B_1$, $B_2$ bilinear forms $\colon V\times V \to k$ such that $B_1(x,y) = 0 \implies B_2(x,y) = 0$. Then  $B_2 = c\cdot B_1$ for some $c \in k$. Indeed, fix $x \in V$. As above, we get $B_1(x,y) = 0$ implies $B_2(x,y) = 0$. We conclude $B_2(x,y) = c(x) \cdot B_1(x,y)$. But in the same way we get $B_2(x,y) = c'(y) \cdot B_1(x,y)$. We conclude $c(x) = c'(y) = c\in k$.

Now apply the above result to $(x,y) \mapsto x' A y$, and $x' A' y$. We conlude that $A$, $A'$ are proportional. The proportionality constant can only be $\pm 1$.

Comment: How to show $c(x)=c'(y)=c$?

Comment: @xldd: Say we have a function $C(x,y)$, that depends only on $x$, and only on $y$. Then the function is constant. Why?  $C(x,y) = C(x, y') = C(x', y')$.